# cordova Error: Please install Android target: "android-22" (When I already have 23)

Tags: android, cordova

Cordova gives me this error, when I was making my first hello world app.

I typed :

```
cordova build android
```

And I got the follwing output:

```
[Error: Please install Android target: "android-22".

Hint: Open the SDK manager by running: /home/nicki/Android/Sdk/tools/android
You will require:
1. "SDK Platform" for android-22
2. "Android SDK Platform-tools (latest)
3. "Android SDK Build-tools" (latest)]
ERROR building one of the platforms: Error: /home/nicki/code/cordova/hello/platforms/android/cordova/build: Command failed with exit code 2
You may not have the required environment or OS to build this project
Error: /home/nicki/code/cordova/hello/platforms/android/cordova/build: Command failed with exit code 2
    at ChildProcess.whenDone (/usr/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/cordova/superspawn.js:139:23)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:98:17)
    at maybeClose (child_process.js:766:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:833:5)
```

I am using Ubuntu 14.04.

Android Manifest file in my app:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<manifest android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="0.0.1" package="com.example.hello" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <supports-screens android:anyDensity="true" android:largeScreens="true" android:normalScreens="true" android:resizeable="true" android:smallScreens="true" android:xlargeScreens="true" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <application android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name" android:supportsRtl="true">
        <activity android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale" android:label="@string/activity_name" android:launchMode="singleTop" android:name="MainActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <intent-filter android:label="@string/launcher_name">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="14" android:targetSdkVersion="22" />
</manifest>
```

I also modified `<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="14" android:targetSdkVersion="22" />` to

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="14" android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
```

and it still gave same error of android-22 (even though it was 19 in the file).
And besides that I got 23 which is even better than 22, as you can see in my screenshot below:
[image]

Comment: so, if it ask for 22 install 22

Comment: Yeah I am downloading it, lets see if it solves this.

Comment: worked!!.... after installing 22

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this can be the issue with Cordova version you are using. Each version of cordova will support only a set of android version. Please read this for more information: https://cordova.apache.org/announcements/2015/07/21/cordova-android-4.1.0.html

Comment: I got this, Requirements check results for android:
Java JDK: installed .
Android SDK: installed 
Android target: not installed 
Please install Android target: "android-22".

Comment: So I should downgrade my android from 23 to 22? and how to do this? I have reinstall everything or just some things?

Comment: One solution you can add sdk 22  also. No need to reinstall all.  or you can  change the cordova version

Comment: Ok, I think I already have the latest version of cordova, gonna install 22.

Answer (score 1):

Just edit the files listed below as

```
# Project target.
target=android-23
```

- myApp/platforms/android/project.properties
- myApp/platforms/android/CordovaLib/project.properties

From the screenshot i have understand that, you have installed `Android SDK Platform tool` and `Android SDK Build tool` in version 23. So you have to change the Project target as mentioned above on those files.

It worked for me. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm on Windows 7 x64.
For me the problem was that default java.exe was ran from Oracle's JDK 8u40 (on PATH), while my JAVA_HOME pointed to IBM (WebSphere) JDK with WAS 8.5

After I ran

```
set JAVA_HOME=c:\devtools\jdk_8u40
```

in my shell for it to point to Oracle's JDK directory, it started finally working!

Answer (score 0):

This works for me, my specific approach is: remove the reference to the oracle directory from the environment variable of path and reduce the JDK version to 1.8.0u65